# Files as Evidence to ALM

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am getting error as

> This file is not supported

while uploading as evidence to ALM.Is there any specific type of the file which has to be uploaded as evidence in ALM?

Answer (score 0):

Evidence tag will attach any type of files passed in the ‘path’ attribute to the ALM step as evidence.
But you have to ensure the file type is set in mimeTypes.properties  file
src->mimeTypes.properties

Eg:

- xlsx=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- xls=application/vnd.ms-excel
- doc=application/msword
- docx=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- txt=text/plain
- json=application/json